# IMAP how to save **all** attachments

Tags: python, email-attachments, imaplib

I am trying to save excel file attachments from my inbox to a directory. My code is executing just fine because I am seeing the print outs but the attachments wont save in the file directory. Is there something I am missing in my code that is preventing the action of saving?

```
 import email, getpass, imaplib, os, sys


detach_dir = r'\directory link'

user = "test"
pwd = "test"
sender_email = "example@example.com"

m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
m.login(user,pwd)


m.select('"INBOX/somestuff"')

print("ok")



resp, items = m.search(None, 'FROM', '"%s"' % sender_email)
items = items[0].split()

print("ok")

for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)")
    email_body = data[0][1].decode('utf-8')
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body)

    print("ok")

    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue



    subject = ""

    if mail["subject"] is not None:
        subject = mail["subject"]

    print ("["+mail["From"]+"] :" + subject)

    for part in mail.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue

        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        counter = 1

        if not filename:
            filename = 'part-%03d%s' % (counter, 'bin')
            counter += 1

        att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

        if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
            fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()
```

This code saves just one of the attachments in the subfolder but I am looking to get all attachments save to the directory:

```
detach_dir = r'directory link'
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("outlook.office365.com")
m.login('user','pass')
m.select('"INBOX/subfolder"')

resp, items = m.search(None, 'All')
items = items[0].split()

for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)") 
    filename = part.get_filename()
    print(filename)
    att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)
    fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
    fp.close()

    print('check folder')
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: This code saves just **one** of the attachments ... but I am looking to get **all attachments**

Implement [iter-attachments()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.iter_attachments)

```
resp, items = imap.search(None, "(UNSEEN)")

for n, num in enumerate(items[0].split(), 1):
    resp, data = imap.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')

    data01 = data[0][1]
    msg_obj = email.message_from_string(data01)

    for part in msg_obj.iter_attachments():
        filename = part.get_filename()
        print(filename)
```

> **iter_attachments()**
>
> > Return an iterator over all of the immediate sub-parts of the message that are not candidate “body” parts. That is, skip the first occurrence of each of text/plain, text/html, multipart/related, or multipart/alternative (unless they are explicitly marked as attachments via Content-Disposition: attachment), and return all remaining parts.

Used modules and classes:
[class imaplib.IMAP4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4)
[class email.message.EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html)

[Here’s an example of how to unpack a MIME message, using email.message.walk(), into a directory of files:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)

Comment: that function is not recognized. do you have a full script that works with that? maybe I am missing something.

Comment: @orangecodelife: Updated my Answer. Show your Python version.

Comment: the verison I'm using is Python 3